# RMI Server Clustering with many clients

Tags: java, cluster-computing, rmi

I have a question about my system's design. I searched the questions but couldn't find the same situation. So currently I have system that has 1 server and multiple(300+ for now) clients that connects with RMI. Since integrity issues I need to make this system fail safe so I need another server. I don't know how to configure my application for that for now but while doing so I'm wondering that if I could the server side clustered even with load balancing? These two servers are going to be different places with different ip addresses of course and they are comprehensive machines as well.

For example for when a client makes a request it makes the request to more available one.

I searched for external solutions but I'm very new to this stuff. Can you make a suggestion about them as well.

I appriciate the responses. If anything is not clear ask and I will clear it as much as I can.

Comment: Ok I decided that I need to convert my RMI(JRMP) to RMI-IIOP but I need suggestions about this system's design. I want to know if there is a api or external system that might help. I looked up some external application servers like glassfish and websphere. Are they the things I'm looking for? Can I achieve this failover and load balancing with rmi issue with them? So I need responses thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to look up the various Java ORB vendors first and evaluate their products. Before you do any coding.

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm not clear about ORB vendors. As ORB approach I'm going to use RMI is it what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

RMI/JRMP doesn't support that in any way shape or form, but RMI/IIOP with a suitable failover ORB might.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think it is hard to convert from JRMP to IIOP? I looked it up and it doesn't seem much trouble to me. And also what did you mean with "suitable failover ORB" can you explain a little bit more. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are correct, the conversion is very easy. The built-in ORB in Java doesn't have any failover support that I am aware of, but vendor ORBs do: don't ask me which ones.